# htaccess HTTPS redirect excluding HTTPS subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, https

I know it has been asked many times here, but can't find the right configuration for my setup.

**Requirements:**

1. http://www.example.com & https://www.example.com (& example.com) have to redirect to https://test.example.com .  (Notice it is a subdomain)
2. https://sub_1.example.com is to be EXCLUDED and not redirected. (Notice the subdomain has an 'underscore')

**What I Have:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# EXCLUDE following sub-domains.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub_1\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^test\.example\.com$ [NC]
# REDIRECT to
RewriteRule (.*) https://test.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**>> ISSUE:** 
My https://sub_1.example.com is in fact an API that feeds a mobile app.  When I use the above code, the mobile fails.  So it seems that the sub-domain is not properly excluded and protected from the re-direct.

Would appreciate some help in cleaning it up.

Comment: @anubhava - I have seen you guys answer similar questions.  Would you please assist in this specific case ?

Comment: Hi @anubhava ... Thanks for the quick response.
I made a mistake ... this is what needs to be EXCLUDED: https://sub_1.domain.com/api  (notice the /api sub-folder)

Comment: Your rule is already excluding `sub_1.example.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIXED !!**

Needed to add an exception before the existing rules, since I needed to exclude  `https://sub_1.example.com/api`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub_1\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^api - [L]
```